# Página web não abre na minha WebView

Tags: java, android, webview

Fiz um navegador usando *WebView*, mas quando chamo `loadUrl();` ele abre a página no navegador padrão do Android.
Como faço para ele ser aberto dentro do meu navegador?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você precisa definir aonde ele será aberto, por exemplo:

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webView);
myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(), "HTMLOUT");
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
myWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(false);
myWebView.loadUrl(url);
```

Com isso você força a URL a ser aberta no seu WebView declarado no XML.

Abraços.